# How did Smith et al 2004 deal with missing HI [Hemagglutination Inhibition assay] values and HI values <10?

Tags: bioinformatics, virology, computational-model, influenza

In the scientific paper "Mapping the Antigenic and Genetic Evolution of Influenza Virus's" [Supporting Material](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/suppl/2004/07/15/1097211.DC1), Smith et al write about determining antigenic distance Dij. However, I don't understand how one could calculate Dij from HI values of <10. Is it better to remove these data values or to change it to 9?

Also, regarding the missing data, how does one make a comprehensive antigenic map using shape space distance dij? I see that an error function must be minimized, but how does that give dij for all the missing data? Should missing data be ignored for the error function?

Comment: I don't know how Derek's group handles it (don't have time to look now) but conventionally HI assays less than 10 are called "9" for statistical purposes, and I assume that's how they did it. Have you looked at Henry Wan's antigenic distance web site (http://sysbio.cvm.msstate.edu/software/AntigenMap/about)? I think he talks more about his approach

Comment: You're clearly serious about this project, but asking on se.biology isn't the best problem-solving approach for this kind of in-depth question. Can you find a mentor in the field who can work with you specifically?

Comment: Thank you @iayork. I am a high school student and I am working on this project for a research competition. I appreciate your answering my questions for the past few months.

Comment: I'd like to help more, but this isn't my speciality, not to mention that I have my own group to run. Since you have good, specific and focused questions, you could just try writing to [Derek Smith](https://www.pathogenevolution.zoo.cam.ac.uk), who is a very friendly guy. [Trever Bedford](https://github.com/trvrb) is enthusiastic and committed to open-source software and has a strong Twitter presence, and you might get answers from him too. [Jesse Bloom](https://github.com/jbloomlab) is very knowledgeable and has open-source projects.

Comment: Alright, thank you @iayork. I will contact the people whose names you mentioned.